# Navigate to page, scrollTop() always works. Refresh page, scrollTop() never works

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, scroll

I have a problem that's only happening in Safari. I have a certain div that I'm trying to automatically scroll to a certain position after the page loads.

If I type the URL of my page into Safari and hit enter, the div does NOT scroll properly. If I navigate away from that page, then click on a link that takes me back to that same page, the div DOES scroll properly. If I refresh the page, the div goes back to not scrolling.

It's almost as if scrolling works with a primed cache but not with an empty cache, but it doesn't seem like doing a soft refresh would clear Safari's cache, so I don't think that's it.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#under").scrollTop(400);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Works in Chrome? Usually I find Safari and Chrome mirror each other in behavior. A fiddle would be nice too as this `should` work.

Answer (score -1):

Safari sometimes fires DOM ready too early. Try window.load instead:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#under").scrollTop(400);
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to affect anything, unfortunately.